# Problem im reindexing product prices

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.8, magento-1.9, magento-enterprise

I am trying to reindex product prices but it shows me an error "There was a problem with reindexing process". I have already tried database recovery tool but it did not work for me.
Thank You

**Exception log:**

```
2014-11-18T12:40:11+00:00 DEBUG (7): Exception message: SQLSTATE[21S01]: Insert value list does not match column list: 1136 Column count doesn't match value count at row 1
Trace: 
0 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\lib\Varien\Db\Statement\Pdo\Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)

1 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Zend\Db\Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)

2 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\lib\Zend\Db\Adapter\Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)

3 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\lib\Zend\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `ca...', Array)

4 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\lib\Varien\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql.php(428): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `ca...', Array)

5 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Model\Resource\Product\Indexer\Price.php(455): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('INSERT INTO `ca...')

6 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Model\Resource\Product\Indexer\Price.php(379): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Indexer_Price->_prepareTierPriceIndex()

7 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Index\Model\Indexer\Abstract.php(143): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Indexer_Price->reindexAll()

8 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Index\Model\Process.php(210): Mage_Index_Model_Indexer_Abstract->reindexAll()

9 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Index\Model\Process.php(258): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexAll()

10 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Index\controllers\Adminhtml\ProcessController.php(127): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexEverything()

11 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Action.php(418): Mage_Index_Adminhtml_ProcessController->reindexProcessAction()

12 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Router\Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('reindexProcess')

13 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))

14 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()

15 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)

16 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')

17 {main}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason the method `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Indexer_Price->_prepareTierPriceIndex` tries to insert something in a table but the number of values to be inserted is bigger than the number of columns the table has. You should start debugging from there.